# How to do a Negative SumIfs in VBA using Worksheet.Function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010 VBA to do some SumIfs and I need it to perform a negative SumIfs.

Here is a sample of the VBA code where I need it to perform a negative SumIfs:

```
'Define the Vidir Machine Income and Trail Balance ranges
Dim vmIncRng As Range, trBalRng As Range, VMI As Worksheet, TRL As Worksheet

Set VMI = Sheets("VM Income")
Set TRL = Sheets("Exec Trial Balance")

'Define my Ranges
Set vmIncRng = Sheets("VM Income").Range("S4:S52")
With Worksheets("Exec Trial Balance")
    Set trBalRng = .Range("a2", .Range("F2").End(xlDown))
End With

'Overwrite YTD with summed values from Trial Balance
Dim sumVal As Double
For Each c In vmIncRng
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        'Excel Formula: =-SUMIFS('Exec Trial Balance'!E:E,'Exec Trial Balance'!F:F,S6,'Exec Trial Balance'!A:A,"Arborg",'Exec Trial Balance'!B:B,"m1")
        'I need the following line to perform the negative sum          
        sumVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(TRL.Range("E:E"), TRL.Range("F:F"), c, TRL.Range("A:A"), "Arborg", TRL.Range("B:B"), "m1")
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = sumVal
    End If
Next c
```

When using a formula to perform a negative SumIfs I just add a - in front of the SumIfs like so `=-SumIfs(.....` How can I do this in VBA?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean like this `sumVal = - 1 * Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(....)`

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out thanks to Siddharth Rout.

Instead of:

`sumVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(TRL.Range("E:E"), TRL.Range("F:F"), c, TRL.Range("A:A"), "Arborg", TRL.Range("B:B"), "m1")`

I added `-1 *` before the `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

`sumVal = -1 * Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(TRL.Range("E:E"), TRL.Range("F:F"), c, TRL.Range("A:A"), "Arborg", TRL.Range("B:B"), "m1")`

Comment: + 1 I hope you understand the logic behind it?